# how to access then response outside promise in node using imageToBase64

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, backend

I am using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64) to output a base64 format of an uploaded picture and it is working just fine:

```
    imageToBase64("./upload/image.png").then(
    (response) => {
        console.log("Then",response);
    }
).catch(
    (error) => {
        console.log("catch",error);
    }
   
)
```

My problem is how can I get the `response data` from that promise and add that into an node object.